# index.html no aplica CSS ni imagenes

Tags: html, css

tengo mis archivos en una carpeta llamada "Content" de Dropbox con esta estructura:

Content/hojadeestilos.css 
Content/index.html 
Content/img/paisaje.png

Es muy simple pero no puedo hacer que el index.html aplique el estilo de la hojadeestilos.css

el [index.html] contiene:

```html
< !DOCTYPE html >
< html lang="en" >
< head >
    < meta charset="UTF-8">
    < title>Document</title>
    < link rel="stylesheet" href="hojadeestilos.css" type="text/css">

< /head>
< body>
    < h1>paginad de prueba de estilos</h1>

    <img src="img/paisaje.PNG" alt="paisaje">

    < p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos fugit consequatur tempore corrupti ipsa velit sequi possimus, beatae sed, amet dolores fugiat nobis deleniti, officia, doloribus eveniet inventore molestiae quisquam.</p>



</body>
< /html >
```

y [hojadeestilos.css] contiene:

```css
p{
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

La imagen tampoco la toma cuando veo la pagina en el navegador.
Si arrastro el achivo al navegador funciona todo.
Si agrego el estilo dentro de etiquetas `<style>` dentro del `<head>` tambien funciona.

Alguien sabe que podrá ser?

Comment: Es decir, no funciona cuando lo abres desde Dropbox?

Comment: Si abres la consola te dará error 404 en los archivos que no encuentra, mira a ver qué ruta está escribiendo

Comment: Tu html no puede funcionar. no es válido. Por favor quita los espacios de las etiquetas: por ejemplo `<!DOCTYPE html>` en lugar de < !DOCTYPE html >

Comment: Creo que eso se debe a como lo ha copiado, comenta que en el navegador sí que funciona, yo creo que los tiros van más por qué las urls en Dropbox son distintas, puede que no sean relativas al documento `html`

Answer (score 0):

como bien a comentado Enxaneta el fichero html no es valido. Para que sea valido debes quitar los espacios en las etiquetas.

Debe de quedar algo así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hojadeestilos.css" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>paginad de prueba de estilos</h1>

    <img src="img/paisaje.PNG" alt="paisaje">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos fugit consequatur tempore corrupti ipsa velit sequi possimus, beatae sed, amet dolores fugiat nobis deleniti, officia, doloribus eveniet inventore molestiae quisquam.</p>


</body>
</html>
```